# How do I add a suffix to the end of each list element?

Tags: python, list

I have two, unequal length lists. The first list contains variable names for a longitudinal study, the other contains suffixes for these variables. The user supplies a CSV from which the variable names are read, and then is prompted to enter the (n) number of iterations of these variables, and the names of the n number of suffixes

Here is a fake example of what I mean

Number of iterations: 2

Suffix1: pre

Suffix2: 6month

List 1: 
        `['mood1', 'mood2', 'mood3', 'dep1', 'dep2', 'dep3']`

List 2: 
        `['pre', '6month']`

Desired concatenation:

`['mood1_pre', 'mood2_pre', 'mood3_pre', 'dep1_pre', 'dep2_pre', 'dep3_pre', 'mood1_6month', ..., 'dep3_6month']`

I have the program working fully, except the output splits each letter of the concatenated list into its own element, for example:

```
How many iterations of the variables do you need?: 3
Variable Suffix 1: pre
Variable Suffix 2: 6m
Variable Suffix 3: 12m
['B', 'o', 'b', '_', 'p', 'r', 'e', 'J', 'o', 'e', '_', 'p', 'r', 'e', 'J', 'i',
 'm', '_', 'p', 'r', 'e', 'A', '_', 'p', 'r', 'e', 'B', '_', 'p', 'r', 'e', 'C',
 '_', 'p', 'r', 'e', '1', '_', 'p', 'r', 'e', '2', '_', 'p', 'r', 'e', '3', '_',
 'p', 'r', 'e', '1', '4', '_', 'p', 'r', 'e', 'B', 'o', 'b', '_', '6', 'm', 'J',
 'o', 'e', '_', '6', 'm', 'J', 'i', 'm', '_', '6', 'm', 'A', '_', '6', 'm', 'B',
 '_', '6', 'm', 'C', '_', '6', 'm', '1', '_', '6', 'm', '2', '_', '6', 'm', '3',
 '_', '6', 'm', '1', '4', '_', '6', 'm', 'B', 'o', 'b', '_', '1', '2', 'm', 'J',
 'o', 'e', '_', '1', '2', 'm', 'J', 'i', 'm', '_', '1', '2', 'm', 'A', '_', '1',
 '2', 'm', 'B', '_', '1', '2', 'm', 'C', '_', '1', '2', 'm', '1', '_', '1', '2',
 'm', '2', '_', '1', '2', 'm', '3', '_', '1', '2', 'm', '1', '4', '_', '1', '2',
 'm']
```

I am using this to make the new list
`newvarlist.extend((varlist[vars] + '_' + varsuffix[j]))`

Comment: Can you actually show your code? It's hard for anyone to give you advice on it without seeing it.

Comment: You probably are iterating over strings in the list. Although it is hard to comment on your approach without the code.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is one way to do it using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
['{}_{}'.format(a, b) for b in b_list for a in a_list]
```

Demo:

```
>>> a_list = ['mood1', 'mood2', 'mood3', 'dep1', 'dep2', 'dep3']
>>> b_list = ['pre', '6month']
>>> result = ['{}_{}'.format(a, b) for b in b_list for a in a_list]
>>> result
['mood1_pre', 'mood2_pre', 'mood3_pre', 'dep1_pre', 'dep2_pre', 'dep3_pre', 'mood1_6month', 'mood2_6month', 'mood3_6month', 'dep1_6month', 'dep2_6month', 'dep3_6month']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are flexible on the ordering of the final list:

```
from itertools import product, imap
l1 = ['mood1', 'mood2', 'mood3', 'dep1', 'dep2', 'dep3']
l2 = ['pre', '6month']
x = list(imap('_'.join, product(l1, l2)))
```

This produces `['mood1_pre', 'mood1_6month', ...]` rather than `['mood1_pre', 'mood2_pre', ...]`.